# CodeBuild: how to pass variables / JSON data to an CloudWatch Event Rule?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-codebuild

Codebuild is used to build a project from a repository and deploy it to s3. I want to pass data/information that is processed in codebuild to cloudwatch event so that I can send the notification with that information for pass as well as failed build. Is there a way to send data ($variables) processed in codebuild in cloudwatch event rule or any other way?

I have the rule, topic, and email working.... but I see no way to pass any extra data than what is supplied by CodeBuild.

For example: I have some environment variables in code build and I need to send these as a part of my notification which will help me determine what value caused the failure of build.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to pass some of the variables/data that are generated in CB itself (i.e., some variables from clone and building of project on the go like repo branch, commit hash info, etc.) EventBridge and build-in notification events from CB cannot pass this information into lambda subscribers without using AWS CLI in CB itself. So I ended up using build-in the notification of CB to send event status msg to SNS topic to subscriber to lambda and parse that event for status (PASS/Failed). As for git info, I dumped webhook JSON into S3 and parsed it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this form with your CB as part of your `buildspec.yml`. If you are using SNS (I guess), then you can use [aws sns publish](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sns/publish.html) AWS CLI as part of your CB procedure. This would also require you to add permissions to CB role for `sns:publish` action.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I need to pass the **PASS/ FAIL** status of the codebuild in SNS as well. I could use AWS CLI command to push message to SNS in the Finally block of a particular phase but there are multiple phases like install, pre-build, build... can I use Finally as for the whole codebuild to pass the status (PASS/ FAIL) as we would get through cloudwatch event rule?

Answer (score 1):

I'll start with saying that @Marcin answer is totally correct but it doesn't answer the "as well as failed build" part.

So for the first part where you want to send the responses from the processed data you either need to:

- [publish to SNS directly from your buildspec](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Publish.html) (as @Marcin pointed out)
- or [send an event to AWS EventBridge (aka Cloudwatch Events)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-putevents.html) from your buildspec

With regard to the second part of the question where you want to catch the CodeBuild execution status you can rely on the [built-in notifications events from that are generated from CodeBuild itself](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-build-notifications.html#sample-build-notifications-ref):

```
{
  "source": [ 
    "aws.codebuild"
  ], 
  "detail-type": [
    "CodeBuild Build State Change"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "build-status": [
      "IN_PROGRESS",
      "SUCCEEDED", 
      "FAILED",
      "STOPPED" 
    ],
    "project-name": [
      "my-demo-project-1",
      "my-demo-project-2"
    ]
  }  
}
```

You can intercept the events for the whole build and for each phase separately if needed and act upon them (whether you are going to send to SNS, or trigger a Lambda or something else it's up to you).

Comment: thank you for the answer. Actually, I wanted to pass some of the variables/data that are generated in CB itself (i.e., some variables from clone and building of project on the go like repo branch, commit hash info, etc.) EventBridge and build-in notification events from CB cannot pass this information into lambda subscribers without using AWS CLI in CB itself. So I ended up using build-in the notification of CB to send event status msg to SNS topic to subscriber to lambda and parse that event for status (PASS/Failed). As for git info, I dumped webhook JSON into S3 and parsed it.